# Instantiate FetchEvent in Jest for a Cloudflare Worker

Tags: typescript, jestjs, cloudflare-workers

The [TypeScript template repository](https://github.com/cloudflare/worker-typescript-template) for Cloudflare Workers has a test for mocking a GET request whereby `Request` is instantiated to mock the input parameters for `handleRequest`.

However, I've since modified the template to pass the raw `FetchEvent` to the `handleRequest` method, rather than `FetchEvent.request` (which is the default). Now, I need to instantiate `FetchEvent` in my test for passing to `handleRequest`, rather than `Request`.

Where can I import `FetchEvent` from? My first thought was to add `node-fetch` as a dev dependency, but it looks like that library doesn't provide a `FetchEvent` implementation.

Is there a way of mocking the `FetchEvent` without needing to resort to another external dependency (i.e. within the Cloudflare Workers library)?

Answer (score 2):

```
import { handleEvent } from '../src/handler'
import makeServiceWorkerEnv from 'service-worker-mock'

declare var global: any

function createEvent(request: Request): FetchEvent {
  // @ts-ignore Sadly the typing seem to be off here, creating a FetchEvent is valid in a test environment.
  return new FetchEvent('fetch', { request })
}

describe('handle', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    Object.assign(global, makeServiceWorkerEnv())
    jest.resetModules()
  })

  test('handle GET', async () => {
    const fetchEvent: FetchEvent = createEvent(
      new Request('/', { method: 'GET' }),
    )
    const result = await handleEvent(fetchEvent)
    expect(result.status).toEqual(200)
  })
})
```

Let me know if it works